# Should Lightning Message Service (LMS) work from a Lightning Web Component Action?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service, custom-actions

I've just moved some logic from one LWC into a "headless" `@api invoke()` LWC that is configured as an [Action that appears as a button](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/05/learn-moar-with-summer-21-lwc-quick-actions) in the standard "Highlights Panel" LWC. The method is called, but the [LMS](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communicate-between-lightning-web-components/communicate-between-unrelated-components) message does not make it to the subscribing components.

This [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/05/learn-moar-with-summer-21-lwc-quick-actions) says:

> ... you can take advantage of all of the great services provided in the
> LWC framework. For example you can use Lightning Data Services to get
> data from Salesforce, you can use Apex to perform complex operations
> and you can use Lightning Navigation Service to navigate to other
> pages in Salesforce.

and this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation)

> ... communicate across the DOM between Visualforce pages, Aura
> components, and Lightning web components, including components in a
> pop-out utility bar.

Reading this [Define the Scope of the Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel_scope) hasn't answered this question for me, and no joy Googling so far. Oh and the description of `APPLICATION_SCOPE` there isn't clear for me.

Some debugging revealed (first value is `messageContext`, second value is `messageChannel__default['default']`):

```
// For the action LWC publish
Symbol(MessageContext_597a18b7_ed66_43b1_bef1_04a6d1ba2b36)
81c785fd_958c_4725_b81f_4c3ac302b7a3

// For a component in the flexi-page body publish
Symbol(MessageContext_0aeda8b3_b4aa_4ad6_a926_78c3ac1736ce)
81c785fd_958c_4725_b81f_4c3ac302b7a3

// For a second component in the flexi-page body publish
Symbol(MessageContext_a3db5e30_9587_4d75_a447_52709b626c0e)
81c785fd_958c_4725_b81f_4c3ac302b7a3
```

so no obvious difference there.

I assumed that LMS should work in this context and the problem is something I've messed up on. But now I'm not so sure. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, Lightning Message Service (LMS) does work from a Lightning Web Component Action. The `APPLICATION_SCOPE` does not necessarily have to be set.

(My problem was that a component I had removed from the UI at the same time contained the subscriber. This code was written by someone else, and the subscriber component being "hidden" within the component I removed was a surprise to me.)

Comment: Really glad it was user error rather than a product limitation :)

Comment: Yeah @PhilW me too. One of those cases where nothing in the docs so that added a bit of uncertainty.

Comment: Is there a way to go around the requirement to have a Lightning Web Component Action? For example I want to pass a simple string state value each time it has changed.

Comment: Will it work on change or focus events for example?